# Node.js bot with Cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I have some `.js` files that take information from web pages with Cheerio, but what I want to do is give them kind of `setTimeout` like 1 day period to restart themselves if there is new data comes or not. I guess I shouldn't do with `setTimeout` because I'll have 15-20 files bot that getting data, I should use thread but how am I going to use them like service.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, 15-20 sounds fine for me to use `setTimeout`.

I thought you might want to check some cron tools like: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule and then schedule your crawlers to rescan targets as you need, as this would be more efficient.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply I'll check

Comment: I'm trying this whatabout running my bots , do i need to use something else to keep running my files at server. Because without service or someting like this file can be stoped at server when I  logout my server

Comment: About that, pm2 might be helpful

Comment: I guess figured out with
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/myApp
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node boot.js
Restart=always
it keeps my server.js alive

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) for node, its an implementation of cron and is really simple to use. This will allow you to schedule tasks to be ran when you want them to. It will also allow you to schedule tasks with out overloading your server with setTimeout but from what you say you wont have many so it wont make too much of an impact.

Comment: Now I implemented cron it works well but wondering that if I put my bot at server(remote linux) then start with node mybot.js , isn't it gonna be closed whenever I left the server ?Do i need service or something like that

Comment: You will need to run Node in something like [screen](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Screen) but the best practice and best way is to use [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) which is a service which runs on your server and monitors and keeps your Node process running.